# PostgreSQL equivalent query which has order by clause alone

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Please help me to get equivalent PostgreSQL query for the below oracle query

```
SELECT sum(COLUMN1),sum(COLUMN2) 
FROM Table_name  
ORDER BY COLUMN3;
```

Comment: 1) The query gives ONE output record. Ordering makes no sense. 2) `COLUMN3` is included into neither aggregate function nor grouping expression. So ordering by it gives random records order. 3) PostgreSQL do not allow partial grouping. So the equivalent not exists.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is completely useless even in Oracle as it won't change the result of the query which I already commented on your previous question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent is simply:

```
SELECT sum(COLUMN1),sum(COLUMN2) 
FROM Table_name;
```

As the order by is useless in any rdbms.